# Layered navigation not displaying on my theme (Venedor theme - Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I just finished (or at least I thought I finished) a Magento shop (version 1.9) but the layered navigation feature is not displaying on  my category page.

-Yes, the category is anchored.

-Yes, I set up the attributes and the attributes sets.

-Yes, I selected the two and three columns layout, but nothing happens

-Yes, I changed the theme to the default one and layered navigation shows up.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

This is the code I have in catalog.xml in my layout:

```
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <remove name="left" />
    <remove name="right" />
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Please check themes catalog layout file to make sure the layer navigation block is added or not.

Comment: Well, I have a section in my catalog.xml that has a comment saying it's staring the layered navigation block...

Comment: I've pasted to code in my main post :)

Comment: It this is third party theme , please check admin configuration for layer navigation

Comment: You said that you have set up the attributes - can you confirm that the attributes you'd like to show were configured to be of the type `dropdown`, and that you have `Use In Layered Navigation` set to **Filterable (with results)**?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. Also, I can confirm like I wrote on the main post, that the layered navigation is showing on all other themes.